# shell script executing network configuration hangs over tmux

Tags: shell, tmux

I am executing a shell script which is doing some network configuration.
when i execute this script using tmux it hangs.

===
Here how I am executing `tmux` in my bash

```
ARGS=$*
tmux new-session -d -s ISA_INSTALL "./installaccess $ARGS"
tmux attach
```

=====
Command which hangs is

`0 16:54:33 cmd /usr/bin/ssh -x -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/var/tmp/installaccess-201607251641FNK/_ssh_%h -o ControlPersist=yes 10.209.192.171 "LC_ALL=C; LANG=C; export LC_ALL LANG; /sbin/ip addr flush eth2 >/dev/null 2>&1; /sbin/ifconfig eth2 down >/dev/null 2>&1" 2>/dev/null
0 17:08:18 CPI WARNING V-9-20-1051 Interrupt Received--installaccess terminated`